# Regex only allow alphanumeric and at least two characters

Tags: php, regex

I am using PHP and have a string that I need to validate that must be...

- Only A-Z and 0-9
- Not one character in its own
- Can not be just numbers on their own
- Can be just letters on their own

I have what I think is the correct regex for only A-z and 0-9 which is...

```
if(preg_match('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i', $string))
{
  echo "not valid string";
}
```

but how do I add to this to also ensure that it is at least two characters long?

Comment: You could do something with `strlen()` or whitematch instead of blackmatching `/^[a-z0-9_-]{2,}$/i`.

Comment: What programming langage is this?

Comment: Here comes [the chameleon question !](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478)

Comment: Question updated with language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$

start string, any character in a-z or A-Z or 0-9, matched two or more times, end string.
```

http://regex101.com/r/sN7tX4

Comment: That works perfectly.  How about adding to it so that it cannot contain all numbers, but can contain all alpha characters?

Comment: Note that if you use `{2}` instead of `{2,}`, then the string will have to only contain 2 chars, no less, no more.